# React JS - Toggle drawer and resize not working together in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to do toggle drawer and resize of it together using React JS and Material UI. The reference code is in class based component at

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2h1g6x?file=ResponsiveDrawer.js

I'm trying to do similarly using function based components and hooks and the codesandbox link is below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/resizeeee-ilot8?file=/src/App.js

But this is not working properly. Initially on toggle the drawer expands and on toggle again it collapses which is fine. But the issue starts when I toggle the drawer and trying to resize it. The width of the drawer changes continuously with mousemove on both outside of drawer and inside of drawer. I understood that my state is changing continuously and so mousemove. Is there any way to restrict this and let it work similarly to the class based component. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change condition on line number 97

```js
if (!state.isResizing || !open)
```

just change  "&&" to "||"